# react-native-push-notification how to show badge number on iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-push-notification

I'm a noob here, and I just faced a problem.
The problem is that the app badge number won't show when a notification arrives/received.

I tried this:

```
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('notificationActionReceived', action => {
  PushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(10) // 10 is just to test
});
```

and this:

```
PushNotification.configure({
  ...

  onNotification: function(notification) {
      PushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(10) // 10 is just to test
  },

  ...
})
```

But still not working.